# Adding items to a second table SQLite in Android Studio does nothing

Tags: sqlite, android-studio

I think my problem is simple and I'm not being able to see the solution, but, when I add data to my second table it does nothing but showing the Toast that it is not working.

This is my DatabaseHelper.java:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " + COL1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COL2 + " TEXT);";

    String createTable2 = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME2 + " ( " + COL3 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL4 + " TEXT,"
            + COL5 + " INTEGER," + COL1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COL6 + " TEXT, " + " FOREIGN KEY (" + COL1 + ") REFERENCES "
            + TABLE_NAME + "(" + COL1 + "));";

    db.execSQL(createTable);
    db.execSQL(createTable2);
}

public boolean addData2(String newEntry1, String newEntry2, String horarios, Integer id_ppl) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL4, newEntry1);
    contentValues.put(COL5, newEntry2);
    contentValues.put(COL1, id_ppl);
    contentValues.put(COL6, horarios);


    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME2, null, contentValues);

    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
```

This is my mainactivity.java

```
buttonNewPill.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String newEntry1 = editText2.getText().toString();
            String newEntry2 = editText3.getText().toString();
            String textSp1 = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String textSp2 = spinner3.getSelectedItem().toString();

            String horario = textSp1 + ":" + textSp2;

            Integer id_ppl = 1;

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "horario is "+ horario, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        /*

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "text is "+ textSp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        */

            if (editText2.length() > 0 && editText3.length() > 0){

                AddData2(newEntry1, newEntry2, horario, id_ppl);

                editText2.setText("");
                editText3.setText("");

            } else {
                toastMessage("Isn't your field empty?");
            }

        }
    });

private void AddData2(String newEntry1, String newEntry2, String horario, Integer id_ppl) {

    boolean insertData = mDatabaseHelper.addData2(newEntry1, newEntry2, horario, id_ppl);

    if (insertData){
        toastMessage("Data Succesfully entered");
    } else {
        toastMessage("Oops! Something went wrong");
    }

}
```

All classes are well acommodated, the contructors were made, and it doesn't have any syntaxes error (I think), since it lets me execute my app in my telephone. But I got the problem described above.

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Comment: Replace `insert` with `insertOrThrow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your, I believe, issue is that you are trying to define multiple PRIMARY INDEXES for the 2nd table.

That is you have :-

- for COL3 `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`
- for COL1 `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`

You can only have a single PRIMARY INDEX (you can have multiple non-primary indexes).

If you looked at the log, you would have had something similar to (when you first ran):-

```
05-11 01:38:10.133 1215-1215/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{soanswers.soanswers/soanswers.soanswers.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table "tbl002" has more than one primary key (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE tbl002 ( column3 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, column4 TEXT,column5 INTEGER,column1 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,column6 TEXT,  FOREIGN KEY (column1) REFERENCES tbl001(column1));
```

So at a guess you would want :-

```
String createTable2 = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME2 + " ( " + 
    COL3 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + 
    COL4 + " TEXT,"
            + 
    COL5 + " INTEGER," + 
    COL1 + " INTEGER," + 
    COL6 + " TEXT, " + 
    " FOREIGN KEY (" + COL1 + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + COL1 + "));";
```

- Column 1 removed as primary index, although you may want an additional index on COL1 as it references another table.
- You very likely don't really want AUTOINCREMENT, as per

  - > The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and
    >   disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is
    >   usually not needed.[SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

Note that you will need to delete the App's Data or uninstall the App (as long as you can afford to lose any existing data) after making the changes, for the changes to be applied
- There are other ways but this is the simplest.

### Adding the Index (optional):-

The following would add an additional index according to table2 col1 :-

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " + COL1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COL2 + " TEXT);";

    /*
    String createTable2 = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME2 + " ( " + COL3 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL4 + " TEXT,"
            + COL5 + " INTEGER," + COL1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COL6 + " TEXT, " + " FOREIGN KEY (" + COL1 + ") REFERENCES "
            + TABLE_NAME + "(" + COL1 + "));";
    */

    String createTable2 = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME2 + " ( " +
            COL3 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            COL4 + " TEXT,"
            +
            COL5 + " INTEGER," +
            COL1 + " INTEGER," +
            COL6 + " TEXT, " +
            " FOREIGN KEY (" + COL1 + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + COL1 + "));";

    String crtTable2Col1Index = "CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS col1index ON " +
            TABLE_NAME2 + "(" + COL1 + ")"; //<<<< ADDED


    db.execSQL(createTable);
    db.execSQL(createTable2);
    db.execSQL(crtTable2Col1Index); //<<<< ADDED
}
```

- **col1index** would be the name of the index

### Additional

Note as you intend to utilise FOREIGN KEYS you will need to enable FOREIGN KEYS (if you haven't). You can do this by overriding the `onConfigure` method e.g. :-

```
@Override
public void onConfigure (SQLiteDatabase db) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
    } else {
        db.execSQL("pragma foreign_keys = ON");
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, and is doing exactly what I was expecting. Thank you very much for your time and support.